# Same page refreshes upon Authentication, laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 framework on windows. I installed xampp, and created a database. And the following command created two tables in the database: users and password_reset

```
php artisan migrate
```

now I followed every step mentioned in the laravel doc for authentication, but problem is everytime I click register it refreshes the page, without redirecting the page mentioned in authcontroller ( in my case, protected $redirectPath = '/'; )

I checked the database, no changes were made.

So what went wrong???

Comment: Please share your routes, in routes.php, for authentication with us

Comment: Clarify a thing: when you type `php artisan migrate` are the two tables created? (it doesn't care about the routing problem, but I don't undestand why are you mentioning the database)

Comment: Can you publish your routes.php and the controller?